# dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

When I try to `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command to check if a file named format-new exists in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` :

```
ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new
```

If format-new does not exist, create a new file named format-new in the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` directory.

```
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
```